# WordPress getting Ajax error if user is not logged in

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am getting a WP-Ajax error when I try to use some third-party plugins and am not logged in.
For example Contact-form-7. I already disabling the rest-API with the respective plugin, but it didn't change anything. I also tried deactivating themes and plugins. (except the ones I want to use)
The only thing I know is that when I click on the contact form there is the following div created.

```
<div class="ajax-error"></div>
```

So then after some search, I found that if I do the following

```
( defined( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST' ) || defined( 'REST_REQUEST' ) || ( defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) && WP_INSTALLING ) || wp_doing_ajax() ) {
    @ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
}
```

in the wp-includes/load.php so I should be able to see what the exact error is, but I don't get any message, even if I look at the console in Firefox.

So is there a way to see the error message? Or an easy fix for the problems I am having with not-logged-in-users.

I also tried editing the admin-ajax.php, but it didn't seem to have a noticeable effect, although if you have a suggestion what I could add/remove there I will definitely try it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the failing AJAX request.

Comment: I don't know how i can see it, i only see the additional div bein created, but can't get it to show me an actual error message.